# GET request returns a {} but the db table has entries (Spring boot+JPA+MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have tried to receive all the entries in a table as JSON objects, get request shows '200 OK' but it returns a [{}].

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "man")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "man_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "man_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Double salary;
    @Column(name = "reg")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
}
```

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {
}
```

Service Layer

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    public List<User> findAll(){
        return userDAO.findAll();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/man")
public class UserControl {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserControl(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<User> findAll(){
        return userService.findAll();
    }
}
```

apllication.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: root
    password: onionnetwork

    jpa:
      hibernate.dll-auto: update
      generate: true
      show-sql: true
```

Used Dependencies: starter-web , stater-jpa , mysql connector

**NOTE**: I'm currently learning spring boot through YouTube tutorials, so there will be some cringy programming practices.If you guys could help me with reviews and good resources to learn spring-boot, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Just to double-check: you are sure that your `man` table contains data?

Comment: Always follow official blogs

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Comment: @TobiSH yes it contains data, and there is a table but when I try post it gives this exception **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'starbucks.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist**

Comment: You already have the `show-sql` setting set to true so you should be able to see what kind of queries are made. Maybe this give you a hint